# Detect if div becomes visible, and change color in 10 seconds

Tags: jquery, time, hidden, visible

So I'm displaying a button. When you click it, it shows a red square that had display:none. The element inline-style for the square now is display:block.

I'm trying to detect that once the square has display:block, alert a message, and change the color to yellow **after 10 seconds have passed**.

Here is the code that doesn't seem to work, particularly the jQuery if statement that doesn't run:

```
$("#shower").click(function() {//click to show red square
$('#DivBlock').show();
});

if ($('#DivBlock').css("display") != "none") {//statement does not work
alert ("Visible for 10 seconds, then turn yellow!"); //need to alert this immediately
$('#DivBlock').addClass('yellow'); //need to do this after 10 seconds 
}
```

Any idea how to fix this?
http://jsfiddle.net/LnPpe/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#DivBlock').addClass('yellow');
}, 10e3);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uQk2n/).

Answer (score 0):

The first issue would be that you are not explicitly calling your if statement.  I am guessing that this code resides in the `$(document).ready()` block, in which case it will only be run when the document first loads.  It does not continuously run as written.

Since you are triggering the showing of the red square by clicking the button, you do not need a listener function that 'detects' when it happens.  You know when it happens, when the button is clicked.  So put you timeout and color changing code right there:

```
$("#shower").click(function() {//click to show red square
  $('#DivBlock').show();
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#DivBlock').addClass('yellow');
  }, 10000);
});
```

Unless there is something else I don't know, this should do it.